# How to stop Git branch in IntelliJ?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I was doing some experiments on branch. Finally I decided that experiments were ok. And now I wish to incorporate all changes into main branch.

How to do this with IntelliJ?

In other words, how to move green and purple labels to latest commit?

[image]

I am trying various commands but failing. Sometimes I am getting detached head, in other times I am getting other things, but I can't move labels.

I am not using Git terminology deliberately, because I don't understand actually what it means. Appreciate any explanations!

Interested in IntelliJ solutions.

**UPDATE**

When I am opening branches menu, I get the following picture:

[image]

Comment: Are you using github? The "correct" way would be to open a pull request (PR) on the github website and merge it there (all in your browser). But if you'd be OK with a pure git (no IntelliJ) solution, I can show you how.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using feature branches, since there is a copy of your local branch on the remote ("`origin`") repository. I'll assume that it is there for others to review and approve and so would want the merge into 'origin/master' to be done on the remote server. That part would not be done in IntelliJ.

Once the feature branch has been merged into origin/master on the remote repo,

You would do the following in IntelliJ:

1. Switch to your local `master` branch if you are not on it already ( VCS | Git | Branches... ) then select ( `master -> origin/master` | Checkout )
2. Update your local `master` branch to the latest `origin/master` branch ( VCS | Git | Pull... | select `origin/master` )

If you do not have an app like `github` or `bitbucket` to do pull requests or merge from branch to branch on the remote repository, you will have to update `origin/master` on the remote server from your local repository. To do that, you will have to add a step or two:

1. Switch to your local feature branch if you are not on it already ( VCS | Git | Branches... ) then select ( `removing_old_query` | Checkout )
2. Being doubly sure you have the latest changes, push your local feature branch `removing_old_query` to the remote `origin/master` branch ( VCS | Git | Push | select 'removing_old_query' ) Before hitting the "Push" button, you will see a list of possible commits you can push.  The destination branch will look like a hyperlink and will say something like `origin : removing_old_query`. Click on that hyperlink, and change the remote branch to `master`, then hit "Push".
3. Synchronize your local `master` to the updated `origin/master` by checking out your `master` branch and doing a pull as described above.

Hope that helps.

Comment: See my update please. I can't "switch" to local master branch, because when I am clicking it, a sum-menu appears with 8 entries and no one says "switch".

Comment: In ( VCS | Git | Branches... | Local Branches section ) do you see `master -> origin/master`? When you click on it is there an option that says "Checkout"?